# Алгоритм распределения групп людей по помещениям

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, оптимизация

Уже несколько месяцев никак не могу подобрать алгоритм/метод, с помощью которого можно выполнить следующую задачу.

Есть группы людей (50 групп). В каждой группе разное количество людей (от 1 до 100). Есть помещения (около 20). Эти помещения могут вместить в себя разное количество людей (от 180 до 300). Помещения находятся в разных частях города. Группы людей тоже находятся в разных частях города.

Как можно распределить группы людей **не дробя** их на подгруппы в эти помещения, чтобы в помещениях в идеале не оставалось свободных мест (ну или 1-3 свободных можно оставить, но не желательно) и чтобы группы людей находились как можно ближе к помещению, в которое они будут распределены. Некоторые помещения можно полностью оставлять пустыми.

Попробовал делать методом прямого перебора вариантов - потребовалось несколько часов, чтобы рассчитались все возможные варианты распределения при 10 группах людей и 5 помещениях. Время расчета растет в геометрической прогрессии, если увеличивать количество групп и помещений.

Comment: Ваша задача - это классическая задача о ранце, только немного модифицированная: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5
  Тут можно почитать про идею, реализацию лучше поискать или написать самому.

Comment: Axenow, про задачу о ранце знаю. Проблема в ее применении в том, что у меня нельзя дробить группу людей на подгруппы.

Comment: В помещение можно посадить две группы? Если да - вот и раздробленность. Т.е. тут она наоборот, комнату можно дробить на "подгрупы". А людей назвали группами специально - что бы созвучность слов сбивала с толку.

Comment: Замените комнату на ранец, её размер на вместимость, а группу - на предмет, вес которого равен количеству людей в группе. И вот она, задача о ранце. С учётом дополнительного условия минимума расстояния необходим полный перебор вариантов и минимизация критерия.

Comment: Основная проблема - у Вас не сформулирован критерий оптимума. *чтобы группы людей находились как можно ближе к помещению, в которое они будут распределены* можно как минимум трактовать двояко: 1) минимизировать максимальное из расстояний; 2) минимизировать сумму расстояний. Реально же вариантов оптимума - дофига, а нужен один.

Comment: Akina, в том и проблема, что раскидать нужно оптимально, а самого критерия оптимальности нет. В результате может быть несколько вариантов распределения, из которых человек уже будет выбирать сам.

Comment: Про ранец вам подсказали, а про определение оптимального набора пар группа-помещение - смотрите Венгерский Алгоритм.

Comment: nick_n_a, кстати, никто не сбивал с толку, это не задача в ВУЗе и т.п., это, так сказать, производственная необходимость. Распределение школьников, сдающих экзамены, по пунктам приема экзаменов. Т.е. школьников из одной школы нужно поместить строго в один пункт приема экзаменов (другую школу), т.е. не разбивать школьников из одной школы на несколько пунктов приема экзаменов. Пункт приема экзаменов можно компоновать школьниками из нескольких школ, но не превышая общую вместительность пункта приема экзаменов.

Comment: Axenow, попробовал реализовать алгоритм с ранцем. Что-то получилось, но оптимального распределения не добился (остаются нераспределенные группы людей). Надо пробовать реализовывать алгоритмы, предложенные в комментариях другими пользователями...

Answer (score 2):

Это задача 1d bin packing или сutting stock problem. Точные алгоритмы - экспоненциальные, т.е. все комбинации перебирать нужно. Ускорить перебор можно методом ветвей и границ (негодные варианты рано отсекаются).

Кроме того, можно с помощью динамического программирования проверить, есть ли хорошие наборы для части комнат, и отталкиваться уже от них для сокращения перебора.

Есть эвристические методы, дающие какой-то - не лучший, но, вероятно, не совсем плохой результат. [Случайный пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392143/python-implementations-of-packing-algorithm). [Обзор нескольких примитивных методов](https://www.developerfusion.com/article/5540/bin-packing). Видел качественный обзор c рассмотрением десятка эвристик, но пока не нашёл ссылку.

Если есть какой-то решатель ILP (задачи **[целочисленного линейного программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)**), то можно ему скормить данные,  с такими задачами оптимизации ЦЛП неплохо справляется (если не брать отдельно стоящие программы, то в scipy есть `optimize.linprog`)

Comment: Забыл добавить важный критерий по расстоянию. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: С критерием расстояний linear solver справится, если задачу правильно ему сформулировать. Но в этом случае задача уже становится похожей на задачу о назначениях или даже о максимальном потоке.

Comment: Надо каждый раз копировать результат, и при следующем поиске начинать с него, это увеличит скорость в разы. И начинать с подбора людей по расстоянию до помещения. Уверен, результаты почти всегда будут идентичными :)

Comment: NewView, именно такой алгоритм я и сделал. Т.е. начинал дальше "ветвить" варианты именно с той ветки, где начинается разветвление на несколько вариантов, не трогая начальную часть дерева решений.